# How to find date time pattern in log file using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

All, 
I am not really good with Regular expression and trying to find the right tool to use to test this, i use regexpal online tester and don't seem to be getting this:

Problem: I have the following Log file that are time stamped : 
Example: `1/27/2012 10:47:50 AM : 0 : ContextManager.Initialize : 0 : Context Manager Initialization Started.`

I am looking for a Regular Expression that will look through the log file and find the date format as listed above if it finds it i will do additional checking which i am already doing. I just need to get the regex to match the following mentioned above.

Here is what i got so far in regards to pattern:

```
@"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}";
```

Main Code: .net c#

```
public void ValidateErrorHandlingMessagesInLogFile()
{
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
       //@"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}"
       //^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
       string Pattern = @"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}";
       ValidateUsingRegularExpression(Pattern, "engine");
}
```

Error Log:

```
1/27/2012 10:47:50 AM : 0 : ContextManager.Initialize : 0 : Context Manager Initialization Started. 
1/27/2012 10:47:59 AM : 0 : RuleEngine:538 : 4 : History definition configuration failure. Update history_definition config parameter to resolve errors reported. history definition configuration failure - Unknown field name [Lie_DosFrom] in entry [MEM_DOS]
```

Comment: So....what happens when you search through the error log with the given regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your reg pattern change like this:

```
@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}";
```

That is, sometimes the date/month contains only 1 digit, your original pattern doesn't indicate that.

In general, the modifier `{m,n}` indicates that this pattern appear at least `m` times and at most `n` times; while `{m}` or `{m,m}` indicates this pattern appears exactly `m` times.

Answer (score 0):

Almost right, but your day and month can be just a single digit, as shown in your example! Also the slash needs to be escaped as otherwise it marks the end of the regex.

Try

```
/\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to find all date-times in `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss` format

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```